# AVD resolution different than expected

Tags: android, canvas, resolution, android-virtual-device

I have some AVDs representinting slightly different resolutions (480x854) and (480x800).
When I use methods to get Canvas' size (getWidth()/getHeight()) they report correctly that it's accordingly 480x854.

The thing is that if I run the code below the image is off the screen:

```
SweepGradient sweepGrad = new SweepGradient(350, 350, 
new int[] { Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA }, null);
circlePaint.setShader(sweepGrad);
canvas.drawCircle(350, 350, 50, circlePaint);
```

The 350, 350, 50 values in the last line mean: x coord, y coord and radius fo the circle.
Also found out that the max 'x' value for the circle of radius 50 to be fully visible is 270 (meaning that somehow canvas x dimension was 320).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that I have asked wrong question.
I tested the app on a real device with same resolution and it is wrong on it too.

The soultion for this was adding a line:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The final question would be. Why does it need this line? It seems that in my case 1 pixel in canvas would be equal to 1.5 pixels of a real device.
Also I think that it isn't the correct solution of the problem as adding the specified line takes huge consequences (what if my app doesn't really support any density and I still want put some image at the exact coordinate?).

**Here is the answer:**
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations